# Passing user input as a paramater (Python)

Tags: python

I'm trying to create the basic question for my blackjack game and I want to pass the user's input as a parameter inside a function I created. I tried running my code inside my terminal and nothing happened. Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

```
#function that passes one parameter that prints a question

def ask_user(a):
    print('Would you like to HIT or STAND?')

#variable that holds the user's input

user_answer = input()

#calling the function and passing the users input as the parameter

ask_user(user_answer)
```

Comment: Your indentation is wrong, plus your function returns nothing.

Comment: I think you're looking for `def ask_user(a): user_answer = input('Would you like to HIT or STAND?')`.

Answer (score 1):

Terminal is waiting for input from you. this will make it clear:

```
#function that passes one parameter that prints a question
def ask_user(a):
     print('Would you like to HIT or STAND?')

#variable that holds the users input
user_answer = input("type user input here: ")

#calling the function and passing the users input as the parameter
ask_user(user_answer)
```

From your comment, consider this:

```
def ask_user():
    user_answer = input("Would you like to HIT or STAND? ")
    print("the users reply is stored in user_answer. And is",user_answer )
ask_user()
```

Comment: Sweet, I get that part. Except how could I write it so that it will ask "HIT or STAND" then store that value as a variable but put it inside a function?

Comment: your input is already stored in a value which you passed in parameter as 'a'. You can add, then to your function:
`if a == 'Hit':
    #do something`

Answer (score 0):

You mean you just want to pass a variable into the function and have it printed as well as another print statement?

```
def ask_user(a):
    print('Would you like to HIT or STAND?')
    print(a) #if you just want it to print your variable 'a'
    return a   # if you want your function to return your input

def ask_user(a):
    print('Would you like to HIT or STAND?')
    return a   # if you want your function to return your input

def ask_user(a):
    print('Would you like to HIT or STAND?: ', a) # prints both on 1 line
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to do something like this:

```
def ask_user():
    print("Would you like to HIT or STAND?")
    return (input("type use input here: "))

my_var=ask_user()

print ("You decided to", my_var)
```

Answer (score 0):

my approach would be something like this, hope this helps

```
def ask_user(a):
        print('Would you like to HIT or STAND?')
        user_answer = input()
        if(user_answer=="HIT"):
              #some code or function call with parameter "HIT"
        elif(user_answer=="STAND"):
              #some code or function call with parameter "STAND"
```